# Run loginhook but get UID of current logged in user

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I hope I'm not asking something that will upset the great minds of stack overflow users; I believe I have done my homework but have come up empty handed.

In OS X, I'm trying to create a loginhook that will check to see if a file exists in the /usr/share folder, and if it does not exists, it should create an empty file with a title of the UID of the user who is logging in.

For example, if my UID is 501, while logging in, the script should check if a file called "501" exists in /usr/share. If it does not exist, it should create it.

The issue I'm running into is that all loginhooks are run as root, so if a file is created, it's file name is simply "0".

The only thing I have come up with thus far is:

```
#!/bin/bash
userID=$(id -u)
if [ ! /usr/share/$userID ]
touch /usr/share/$userID
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help and direction of vego, I've found my answer. Vego was mostly correct in that
    `sudo userID=$(id -u $(logname))`
will produce 501 (because my UID is 501) versus producing 0, which is the UID of root.

The thing about Login Hooks, however it appears, is that the account that runs the script is mDNSResponder. I came to this conclusion because after running my script, I got a file with the title of "65"; a little digging around and I found out which account has the UID of 65 on my machine.

So, the solution is this:
    `userID=$(id -u $1)`
and the reason why this works is because accruing to an [Apple KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/Ht2420), "In the login hook script, the variable $1 returns the short name of the user who is logging in."

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `man 1 logname`.

```
userID=$(id -u $(logname))


# compare
sudo id -u
sudo id -u $(logname)
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought it worked, but when I ran the script, it created a file with the title of 65, which means that an account with the UID of 65 ran the process. Turns out after doing "dscl -plist . readall /users" I was able to find that the account is mDNSResponder..So that's odd. I think you've got me on the right path, though, Vego. :) I'll post an update if I find the answer I'm looking for.